# Where is Toralth in Northeastern Tethyr?

Tags: published-adventures, forgotten-realms, maps

I'm looking to send a party through the *Wyrmskull Throne* in the Forgotten Realms AD&D 2nd edition.  The adventure begins on page 11 talking about:

> ... a chance to explore the undersea world first explored in the *Sea of Fallen Stars* campaign supplement.
>
> the Blue Badger tavern in Toralth, a farming village in northeastern Tethyr between the capital at Darromar and the Amnian rebel city of Riatavin.

The party is on a ship in the *Moonsea* above the *Sea of Fallen Stars* presently and sailing south down the river, but I'm not able to place where this community should be on the maps that I have that include the *Sea of Fallen Stars*.

Where can I locate this city, what major landmarks is it near?

Here is the map I'm using:

[image]

Still not finding any of the cities on the Sword Coast, perhaps they are off the bottom edge?

Comment: Darromar  was sometimes called "Ithmong" on 2e maps. There is about 200 miles of nothing between those two cities. Is there any indication that you *need* to know where *exactly* it is? Or do you need help finding the two cities?

Comment: @nvoigt Not seeing Ithmong either, do you see it on the image?

Comment: No, you cannot see it, it's further south and to the west of Riatavin. Just google for maps that show the whole of Tethyr.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tethyr and Amn are countries nowhere near the Moonsea or the Sea of Fallen Stars. See Amn there in the bottom left, far to the west and south on the Sword Coast? Tethyr is south of Amn, just south of that Forest of Tethyr, lying between Amn and Calimshan. (Tethyr should be described in the other books in the box that map comes with though.)

Toralth would be SSE of Riatavin, near or on the river you can just see that's directly east of the eastern edge of the Forest of Tethyr.

How I would have handled this in my Realms heydays is to just entice the party to enter a random portal that goes to somewhere near Toralth, if not outright drop them through one by fiat. (The Realms is lousy with forgotten and strangely-functioning portals. Perhaps when the moon is just so and the river currents exactly as such, an invisible portal appears in midstream of the River Lis, large enough to move a riverboat. And those conditions happen right now! Poof, the party is halfway across the continent.)

Today I'd just bluntly ask them: "Hey, the next adventure starts in a country thousands of miles away. How about we just say a year has passed and we pick back up with all of you in northeastern Terhyr and about to run into some adventure? C'mon, it'll be fun." The nice thing about skipping time like this too is that *real* adventurers would have downtime and less-adventurous parts of their career. If there's no reason not to, skipping chunks of time can make the adventurers' careers and the world in general feel just that little bit more believable.

Comment: +1 for the mature way of handling verisimilitude I.e. ignoring it.

Comment: I wouldn't even say that it's ignoring it. Travel and life in general take time, and it's *more* realistic to me to avoid "we went from level 1 to level 20 in three weeks" phenomenon by putting natural space between the adventures.

Comment: So even though the *Wyrmskull Throne* is for use with the *Sea of Fallen Stars*, Tethyr is over on the *Sword Coast* far to the west?  Could the map be different in 2nd edition?

Comment: No, the map isn't different. It just starts you in Thethyr. If you want to skip that distant start you'll have to study the adventure and rewrite the beginning portions to set up everything necessary without going all the way there.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I've added the map, not seeing any of the cities in Thethyr, maybe they are off the bottom of my map?

Comment: @WilliamKF Yep. See Amn there in the bottom left? Tethyr is south of Amn, just south of that Forest of Tethyr. It lies between Amn and Calimshan. Tethyr should be described in the other books in the box that maps comes with though. Toralth would be SSE of Riatavin, near or on the river you can just see that's directly east of the eastern edge of the Forest of Tethyr.

Answer (score 2):

According to the map of Amn and Tethyr included in the 2e box set of Lands of Intrigue, Toralth is just SSE of Riatavin and NE of the Eastmost tip of the Forest of Tethir:

[image]

Tethyr itself is the right at the bottom of your map and I've marked the approximate location of Toralth with a red dot:

[image]

Comment: I've updated this answer to meet the standards we expect answers to meet on this site. We hope you keep contributing :-)